# How do you specify the pkg-config path when compiling something with cmake?

Tags: compiling, make, cmake, pkg-config

I want to build ffmpeg with support for the av1 codec on CentOS 7.
I start by following the instructions [here](https://aomedia.googlesource.com/aom/):

```
git clone https://aomedia.googlesource.com/aom
mkdir aom_build
cd aom_build
cmake ../aom
make
sudo make install
```

This writes a file to `/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/aom.pc`.
When I later clone ffmpeg's git repo and try to run `./configure --enable-libaom ...`, it complains that pkg-config can't find the aom.pc file.

This is because if I run `pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config`, I can see that pkg-config only checks here:

```
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
```

It doesn't look in `/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig`, where aom.pc is.
So far, the only fix I've come up with is to run this instead in ffmpeg's git directory:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig: ./configure --enable-libaom ...
```

This works, but I'd rather just tell libaom to write aom.pc to /usr/lib64/pkgconfig in the first place.

Is there any way, when building aom, to tell cmake or make to write the aom.pc file to /usr/lib64/pkgconfig instead of /usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig?

In other projects that have a `./configure` step, I've seen it possible to specify this with `./configure --pkgconfigdir=/usr/lib64/pkgconfig`, but the aom project doesn't have a `./configure` script, so I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: Google, cmake /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=cmake+%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Flib%2Fpkgconfig

Answer (score 0):

You would liked to run a custom `cmake` for libaom something like this:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="./extra_ff_mods" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib
make
make install
```

This will place the files in folder called `extra_ff_mods` and that will contains following sub folders:

```
- include
|
- lib
  |
   - pkgconfig
```

You can change the destination folder as appropriate